# Having trouble accessing all data from mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im trying to run a query that will echo the rowcount from the databse. at the moment it only shows the last one not all of them. Can someone please help me on how to show all the rows instead of just one.

```
    $search = $_GET['pc'];
$approved = 'Approved';
$live = 'Live';
$q = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM store WHERE pc = ? OR plus_1 = ? OR plus_2 = ? OR plus_3 = ? OR plus_4 = ?");
$q->bindParam(1, $search);
$q->bindParam(2, $search);
$q->bindParam(3, $search);
$q->bindParam(4, $search);
$q->bindParam(5, $search);
$q->execute();
if($q->rowCount() > 0){
    while($r = $q->fetch()){
        $local_id = $r['user_id'].;
    }

    $q = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? AND status = ?");
    $q->bindParam(1, $local_id);
    $q->bindParam(2, $approved);
    $q->execute();
    if($q->rowCount() > 0){
    while($r = $q->fetch()){
        $local_id_2 = $r['id'].;
    }

        $q = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM offers WHERE user_id = ? AND status = ? AND approved = ?");
        $q->bindParam(1, $local_id_2);
        $q->bindParam(2, $live);
        $q->bindParam(3, $approved);
        $q->execute();



echo        $viewAll = $q->rowCount();

    }
}
```

if tried echoing all the $local_id and local_id2 but only the first one ($local_id) echos all of the data the rest just echos the last $lcoal_id from the first one.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You keep overwriting `$q->rowCount()`. Save it to a variable name or something that you can echo out for each instance.

Comment: You are overwriting your results in your `while` loops -> `while($r = $q->fetch()){ $local_id = $r['user_id'].; }` / `while($r = $q->fetch()){ $local_id_2 = $r['id'].; }`. So each `while` loop will only return the last result, not all the results

Comment: JayBlanchard i've tried changing the var names but doesnt solve it..  @Sean could you give an alternative on how i can fix it please.. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to show the: number of records or the actual data. Also, it would seem you are after certain offers from approved users from each store but it is not clear. Could you please explain what is the expected output?

Comment: It looks like you need to add your 2nd query inside your 1st query loop, and your 3rd query inside your 2nd query loop. Although if what you need is only the results from the 3rd query, you could simplify this all with a `JOIN` query, and use `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: @Alejandro Arbiza Okay what i am trying to achieve is the rowCount and the data from the last query which will be price description terms and conditions etc.. for now i just need the rouwCount so users can see how maby offers they can choose from.. but if im not able to get the rowcount i would be able to get the data from all availiable offers.. once i get the rowcount i will be able to get the data. To add to this its like 100 stores.. id the search query is in the table then select the user_id attached to the table then use those user_id to filter the search query. Hope this helps

Comment: So, you didn't think that explaining all of that initially would help?

Comment: @Jay Blanchard initially no becasue the issue is that only one record is being shown. Btu now giving how i would like for it to work maybe a different solution would be better for me to use. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Going to use a temporary fix going to create another table including all the data i need.